# Attaching a ground wire to a prong that plugs into an outlet adapter

Tags: electrical, receptacle, grounding, safety, ups

The outlet shown in the image below doesn't have a ground wire connecting to its receptacle. A friend of mine is helping me setup a ups that requires ground wire, however what he did was run a ground wire from the basement and connect it to three way prong which plugs into a wall socket adapter. While this did turn off the warning light on the ups, it doesn't however keep the warning light off the if the ups is connected directly to the wall socket adapter. It only turns off the warning light when the ups is connected to surge protector 1, and being able to only connect it the surge protector causes other issues with the ups.

This really doesn't feel safe at all to me, which is why I haven't used this setup yet. So the question is, how unsafe is this, and how does this setup work/manage to turn off the warning light on the ups?

[image: Outlet setup]

Comment: "This really doesn't feel safe at all to me, which is why I haven't used this setup yet." If so, what's that laptop charger cable doing there?

Comment: All of the UPS’s I have had had built in surge protection so that isn’t really needed. The proper way would be to run the ground wire to the outlet itself this is ok as long as the ground is coming from the same service. As long as your friend capped the hot and neutral on that cord it was a good idea for a temporary fix. Not code compliant but not really unsafe.

Comment: @EdBeal I guarantee the surge protector isn't there to provide surge protection, but rather, to provide 6-10 extra sockets each.

Comment: if the surge is protected, everything on the whole outlet should be grounded; grounds have continuity just like the other wires...

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the receptacle box, with the breaker off of course?